# Flip iPhone viewController after few seconds to show data change

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I want to flip animation of view on button click, so that I can change text and images  on same view controller and it can give cool animation in my iPhone app. 
I have used this code perviously for flip transition:-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewControllerName animated:NO]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view    cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but it will push a new viewcontroller that I don't want.  ***I want  flip this animation on same view***

***Please Help.***

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `[yourViewController.view setNeedsDisplay]` ?

Comment: i was searching for somewhat similar problem... hehehe thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need. This will flip your view without needing a second view. And it provides places to make changes both during the animation and after.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:MYVIEW duration:0.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
    // Make your changes to the view here.
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Do any cleanup necessary here.
}];
```

Comment: Hi Ryan,
 Thanks for your help. It does the trick almost, but it shows previous data when it flips and then it shows everything correctly. 

I want to show view's background image to be shown when it flips. Please help

Comment: You need to do the background image change in the animation. Where I have a comment for make changes here. Anything you do in cleanup will happen after. Anything you do during animation will happen during.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code... This work fine for me.

```
flipView=[[FlipMyGuideViewController alloc]init];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:[self view]
                             cache:YES];


    [self.view addSubview:flipView.view];


    [UIView commitAnimations];
```